# Can't modify the variables contained in another var

Tags: perl

I have a file `command_file` containig a large number of commands destined to configure a router. Those lines depend on variables ($rsdp  and $x2 for this example) that I collecte in my code. Here's the two first lines as an example:

`/configure service sdp $rsdp mpls create`

`/configure service sdp $rsdp mpls description "to-$x2"`

but when I lunch the perl script reading the file and sending the lines as commands to the router using `Net::SSH::Expect`, the variables don't change and get the wanted value. I tried using qq but same result. So the commands sent don't get changed.

Thanks in advance for you time

```
my $k;
my $acdc = 'command_file';
open (my $ac, "$acdc") or die ;
while (my $dc = <$ac>){
    $ssh->send($dc);
    $k = $ssh->read_line();
    print "$k\n";
    }
```

```
B:router# /configure service sdp $rsdp mpls create
Error: Invalid parameter.

B:router# /configure service sdp $rsdp mpls description "to-$x2"                  
Error: Invalid parameter.
```

Comment: Where did you define the variables `$rsdp` and `$x2`?

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do here is essentially templating: you specify the structure of the commands in one place, and the values that go in them in another. There are many templating solutions but an easy one for in-line templates like this is [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template), and just needs a minimal change to your input strings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Template 'fill_in_string';

# presuming this text is from an external source that can't access these variables
my $template = '/configure service sdp {$rsdp} mpls description "to-{$x2}"';

my $rsdp = 'foo';
my $x2 = 'bar';
# now these variables are defined
my $command = fill_in_string $template, HASH => {rsdp => $rsdp, x2 => $x2};
```

Answer (score 2):

So you're reading text strings from your input file. Those text strings contain mentions of Perl variables and you want those variables to be expanded in the string without you doing anything to achieve that.

I'm sorry, but life isn't that easy :-)

The text strings you read from your input file are just dumb text strings. They know nothing about Perl variables. It's up to you to put in the clever work to make this work how you want it to work.

Some people will tell you to use `eval` to do this. Please ignore them. It's too dangerous. What we will do is look for specific strings in your text (strings that will look like the variable names you are interested in) and substitute them for the current values stored in those variables.

For example:

```
$dc =~ s/\$rsdp\b/$rsdp/g;
$dc =~ s/\$x2\b/$x2/g;
```

Notice that I've:

1. Escaped the `$` in the pattern on the left-hand side of the substitution, so it's just a `$` and not a variable sigil.
2. Marked the end of the variable name with `\b` which marks a "word boundary". This is so we only match our specific variable name and not any other, longer variable name that happens to start with our variable name.
3. Using a global replacement (`/g`) in case the same variable name appears more than once in the input string.

This needs to happen at the start of your `while` loop - after you have read the text from the file and before you send it as a command.

Comment: `\W` should probably be `\b`. You want to indicate a word character boundary, and not include the following non-word character in the substitution.

Comment: Yes ! I combined the two anserws and it works perfectly!
the \w eats another carachter, it's better with \b 
So many thanks to you two !

Comment: @Grinnz: Yeah, you're right, of course. Not sure where the `\W` came from.

Comment: Hello,
It's all working fine untll I have this cariable to replace vsi_id[3] :      

$dc =~ s/\$vsi_id[3]\b/$vsi_id[3]/g;

I think I need to replace \b by something else, but I don't know what. 
Can you also tell How to find and learn these delimiters ?

Comment: @FaroukH: This sounds like a new question. So you should probably ask it separately.

Comment: @DaveCross I think it's a continuation of the previous, since I'm trying to replace a Variables which is an array element. I think it's related to brackets. But if you insist I will create the topic

Comment: @FaroukH: Your original question made no mention of some of the variables being stored in arrays - so this is a new question. Also, you might consider accepting one of the answers to this question.

Comment: @FaroukH: It might be time for you to read the [Perl regex tutorial](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut) or even the [Perl regex manual](https://perldoc.pl/perlre).